# Caching secrets retrieved from Secrets Manager

Tags: c#, .net, aws-secrets-manager

I want to use AWS Secrets Manager for storing secrets for RDS in a web application. AWS provides `AWSSDK.SecretsManager.Caching` library to improve performance and reduce the costs. I'm having second thoughts about it. In the perfect world, secrets live in memory only when I need them. On the other hand, with a cache, they live always. Are data in the cache (`AWSSDK.SecretsManager.Caching`) encrypted? Does the cache lower security in practice? Is manual implementation with
`System.Security.SecureString` a better solution? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: If someone compromised your server that they can actively read memory held by your process, then all security measures have already failed and it is too late to do something about it. Think about it, even if the secrets are encrypted in memory, you somehow need to decrypt them, how do you do that in a way that someone running malware on your computer can't detect?

Comment: To add to the comment above, no, the caching library is just a very simple memory cache. But you can and should look at the source code in GitHub

Comment: What I'd find more worrying is that the library did not receive any update since over a year and there is an open issue about not being able to use it with newer .NET Core versions since May this year... So forking it so it is compatible with current package versions might actually be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom extension to the cache and this extension can encrypt/decrypt data in memory. In order to do this, you have to implement `ISecretCacheHook` interface:

```
public class SecretCacheHook : ISecretCacheHook
{
  private readonly IEncryptionProvider _encryptionProvider;

  public SecretCacheHook(IEncryptionProvider encryptionProvider)
  {
    _encryptionProvider = encryptionProvider;
  }

  public object Get(object obj)
  {
    return _encryptionProvider.Decrypt(obj);
  }

  public object Put(object obj)
  {
    return _encryptionProvider.Encrypt(obj);
  }
}
```

and pass the object to the cache configuration:

```
var secretsManagerCache = new SecretsManagerCache(
  new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region)),
  new SecretCacheConfiguration
  {
    CacheHook = new SecretCacheHook(new EncryptionProvider())
  });
```

You can read more about on AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-manager-client-side-caching-in-dotnet/).